# TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I know this question was asked many times before (because I looked here for solution), so excuse me for adding more trash. I'm using [this datetime picker](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/) and in the console I get error:

```
TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
```

Whole HTML document:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/fontawesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker2"/>
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                    locale: 'ru'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't think it's the order of loading scripts (as mentioned everywhere else) and I have all the dependencies. What could be the cause of error?

Comment: I will just mention that the button right to the input is not working due the error.

Comment: Do you have <body> in your actual code wrapped around `div.container`?

Comment: Yes I forgot that. Nothing changed, unfortunately.

Comment: *"Whole HTML document:"* are you sure it's the whole HTML document? there's no other html? no other js? Your problem doesn't appear to be related to the code you have provided.

Comment: You may need to confirm jQuery and other scripts are even loading. Try inside the ready function to just even console.log() something simple. Maybe the paths need to be adjusted to the <script> resources.

Comment: @KevinB yes that's all, there are external CSS and JS files included in <head>, all newest versions

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky jQuery works when I use it in the console, I think the problem might be with moment.js and bootstrap-datetimepicker.js (renamed Tempus Dominus), because there were problems with these two in other threads. But I don't know what it is this time, it doesn't work even in this simple example.

Comment: I can't get it to work using CDN resources for the basic example in something like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ue9w1ryj/5/). Something may simply be off with this library or at least this version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check sequence of js import

tempus dominus with bootstrap 4:

```js
$(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`tether.min.js` also required for `tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js`

tempus dominus with bootstrap 3 (Run in full page mode or set css)

```js
$(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-3/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-3.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-3/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <span class="input-group-addon" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will helps you

Comment: tempusdominus is a library for bootstrap 4? does it has compatibiliity with bootstrap 3?

Comment: it was a question for myself thanks for the answer =D, so it has compatibility with both

Comment: @LPZadkiel Welcome : )

Comment: @RahulMahadik is correct, but also, the instructions on the tempus dominus website differ from what is on github. Namely, I got it working when I explicitly included the moment.js scripts.